# How to conditionally populate a group of columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date <- c('2020-1', '2020-1','2020-1','2020-2','2020-2','2020-2','2020-2','2020-3','2020-3','2020-3','2020-3')
ID1 <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C')
ID2 <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd')
ID3 <- c('xy', 'xz', 'ab', 'ac', 'ac', 'ac', 'zy', 'yz', 'yy', 'zz', 'cc')
value <- c(100, 10, 50, 0, 10, 100, 15, 16, 17, 100, 50)

df1 <- data.frame(date, ID1, ID2, ID3, value)
```

I need to form columns based on unique full ID = ID1_ID2_ID3. This is what I did:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% unite(full_id, c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
full_id.unique <- df2$full_id %>% unique()
df2[,full_id.unique]<-NA
```

Now I'd like to populate these columns with the following logic. Each row of each new column should contain the sum of the values from the "value" column, which are taken from those of its rows for which the date, ID1 and ID2 match the same values from the current row and do not match ID3. For example, the first cell of the A_a_xy column will be equal to 10, because the second line matches the first one by date, ID1, ID2 and does not match in ID3, the rest are 0, and so on. The final result (for the first four added columns) will look like this:

```
A_a_xy <- c(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
A_a_xz <- c(0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
B_a_ab <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
A_b_ac <- c(0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

This is a rather complicated logic for me, I do not know how to approach this task.

Answer (score 0):

We may group by 'date', 'ID1', 'ID2', loop `across` columns from 'A_a_xy' to 'C_d_cc', if the `full_id` value is equal to the 'cur_column()`, get the` sum` of 'value' and subtract the 'value' where the column name matches the 'ID3'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   group_by(date, ID1, ID2) %>%
    mutate(across(A_a_xy:C_d_cc,
   ~ case_when(full_id == cur_column()
    ~sum(value, na.rm = TRUE) - 
    sum(value[trimws(cur_column(), whitespace = ".*_") == ID3]), TRUE ~ 0))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 16
   date   full_id ID1   ID2   ID3   value A_a_xy A_a_xz B_a_ab A_b_ac A_c_ac A_b_zy C_c_yz A_d_yy C_d_zz C_d_cc
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2020-1 A_a_xy  A     a     xy      100     10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 2 2020-1 A_a_xz  A     a     xz       10      0    100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 3 2020-1 B_a_ab  B     a     ab       50      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 4 2020-2 A_b_ac  A     b     ac        0      0      0      0     15      0      0      0      0      0      0
 5 2020-2 A_c_ac  A     c     ac       10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 6 2020-2 A_c_ac  A     c     ac      100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 7 2020-2 A_b_zy  A     b     zy       15      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 8 2020-3 C_c_yz  C     c     yz       16      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
 9 2020-3 A_d_yy  A     d     yy       17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
10 2020-3 C_d_zz  C     d     zz      100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     50      0
11 2020-3 C_d_cc  C     d     cc       50      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    100
```

Comment: Yes, this is a great way to create the desired columns! But they are not quite filled as they should be. This just took the values from the corresponding "value" lines, which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Viktor is your expected output correct i.e. for the first column, you have `10`, whereas I get 110

Comment: I updated with your logic

Comment: Yes, it should be 10, because "own" value should not be taken into account. I described it as "mismatch on ID3".

Comment: Thank you very much, it's still more than I achieved in the 2 evenings)

Comment: @Viktor what about the update now